# Reference a String Array with a String

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

I have created multiple arrays and want to be able to to put them in a list and then have that list, when clicked, display the new list of arrays. Here is what I have come up with so far. I am tring to avoid having to use a switch statement to check every situation.

I starred where I am having the issue. I thought it was pretty elegant idea, but it doesn't work and I am not sure of a work around.

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
static public final String TAG = "Home";
ListView list;
ListAdapter lAdapter;
String listString;
String[] currentList;
String[] home;
String[] BY_RACK;
String[] BY_STATION;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    home = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home);
    BY_RACK = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BY_RACK);
    BY_STATION = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BY_STATION);
    currentList = home;
    setList(currentList);



@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.d(TAG, "id;" + id + " position:" + position + " view:" + v);
    listString = currentList[position];
    listString = listString.replace(" ", "_");
    listString = listString.toUpperCase();
    Log.d(TAG, "liststrgin:" + listString);
    listString.
    currentList = listString; ********

}

public void setList(String[] setl) {
    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, R.id.textView1,setl);
    list.setAdapter(lAdapter);


}
```

Comment: When you say _it doesn't work_, what happens?

Comment: I thought it was pretty elegant idea,  `currentList = listString;`  assigning a String to a String array. I don't think so

Comment: `currentList = listString;` It is never possible. To avoid switch statement you can use `Tags`.

Comment: I am sorry I am pretty new to programing, what do you mean use Tags?

Comment: `currentList = listString;` can't work. (`String[] = String` !).
Why don't you use `ArrayList` or [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? With `HashMap`, you can 'reference' a String[] with a String (`HashMap<String, String[]> hm = new HashMap<String, String[]>();`)

Comment: are you set the string into string[] in the same position?